Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'AppState' could not be found
Getting issue after upgrading react native 0.64.3 to 0.73
E  Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'AppState' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary.Bridgeless mode: false. TurboModule interop: false. Modules loaded: {"NativeModules":["PlatformConstants","LogBox","Timing"],"TurboModules":[],"NotFound":["NativePerformanceCxx","NativePerformanceObserverCxx","AppState"]}, js engine: hermes
2024-08-02 14:47:59.671 26473-27071 ReactNativeJS           com.example                          E  Error: [@RNC/AsyncStorage]: NativeModule: AsyncStorage is null.

incrementally increasing async storage versions (issue persists in all)
clearing all kinds of cache possible.
Uninstall, rebuild and restart the app.


I was also getting this error while upgrading react-native from  0.71.8 to 0.74.4.
I found out that, this is occurring from react-native-webview which installed version was 12.0.2.

I just upgraded it to latest version 13.10.5.
clear the build by running ./gradlew clean in android folder
reset yarn cache and restarted the metro bundler
and rebuild the app yarn android


Already at 13.10.5
Any other package in your mind could be upgraded
